# Saving value of a Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to save a value of a cell in Excel .

Thats the code im using :

```
Dim oldval As Range
Sub Macro0()

Set oldval = ActiveCell

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Variant

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = ActiveCell

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell

If rng.Column = 8 And rng.Value <> "" Then
    'Extract the number part of string
    x = Split(rng2.Value, "_")(0)
    y = Split(rng.Value, "_")(0)

    If y < 1 Or x = "" Then Exit Sub

    If x < y Then
        MsgBox "Attenzione, si sta decrementando di stato un fornitore !"
    Else
        MsgBox "Stato cambiato con successo"

End If
End If


End Sub
```

I need to save the value that was in the cell before it get changed.
I tried using that code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Macro1
End Sub




Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Macro0
End Sub
```

But it doesnt work since im using a Macro that is not located on the Workbook.
I need to do a control after i have saved the old value and check if its higher than the new value that has been insert.
How can I save that old value?
Thanks

EDIT :
@Jeeped
Thats how it looks the file 
[image: File]

Comment: Saving the value of a cell *after* it has been changes is sometimes possible with a `Worksheet_Change` event macro. You're going to have to provide some specific cell addresses (both *rng* and *rng2* point to the same `ActiveCell` in your sample code) and it would be best to see a sample of what is to be saved.

Comment: The only way to do this reliably is to store the values from the sheet in another, hidden (`VeryHidden`) sheet.  You can then compare the new value (using the `Change` event) to the value on the other sheet and then update the hidden sheet after the comparison.

Comment: To get the value of a cell after it's been changed you'll need to use `Application.Undo` and then record the value, and then you can `Application.Undo` again to put the changed value back in

Comment: I have never used those  Application.Undo codes. Would you clear out how to use them? Thanks

Comment: Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have just now fully understood your need. Here is a work-around:

*In your module, add the macro1() like this*

```
Sub macro1(ByVal oldVal As String, ByVal newVal As String)
    MsgBox "The value was " & oldVal & ", but now is " & newVal
End Sub
```

*In your Worksheet module, add the two following events + declarations*

```
Dim oldVal As String, newVal As String 'the top declaration allows you to use the variables even when the macro/method of the worksheet has finished to run
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    newVal = Target.Value 'this will just take the current value of the cell
    Call macro1(oldVal,newVal) 'they are both passed to your procedure
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldVal = Target.Value 'this will record the value of the cell everytime you are selecting it
End Sub
```

Here's how it works, changing the content of the cell from "buongiorno" to "buonasera":

[image]

and

[image]

Of course this is an example, but you will just need to re-adapt the workaround on your code and it should work fine.
Note: I've just figured out the messagebox is showing the message in a different language than what's coded, that happened because I've made a screenshot when I was still testing the method. Sorry about that, please suggest an edit if you think this could create confusion.

Comment: Alright, but it doesnt work here :      `Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = oldVal ` Since i need to do a control on the changed value

Comment: @Kiirito, I still don't understand why you keep on referencing the object rather than its value. `Set rng2 = oldVal` means you're carrying with you the whole range, not only its value... so it's normal if the value call will give you back the current value, because you're bringing with you the range object and not its value! Please try to use the example as I shown you in the code, where I defined `As String` (or whatever is your value data type), or change the question title because you're asking the value of the range :)

Comment: I'll try to adapt it . Thanks mate ! If im not able to adapt it i'll open a new thread with the problem.

Comment: Look, you don't need to adapt it, just to clear your ideas. If you say `Dim rng2 As Range`, it means that you are defining the variable to be a `Range` object. Hence, `Set rng2 = oldVal` can only store an object. My question is: do you need to bring in your `Macro1()` the **value** or the entire **range**?

Comment: The value, since I need to compare with the old one

Comment: Perfect. So, what kind of value is this? Is it an integer, a string, a double or what else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64348/discussion-between-kiirito-and-matteo-nnz).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare the variable at the project level. Here's a simple example:

```
Dim a As String
Sub macro1()
    a = Range("A1")
End Sub
Sub macro2()
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

If you run the macro1, the variable a (which is declared at the top level) will store the value of the cell Range("A1"). Then, if you run macro2 in a second moment, the value will be still there.

You just need to declare your variable `oldval` on the top of your project and store your old value as with `oldValue = ActiveCell.Value` put just before you made your changes. The variable will hold the value even after getting out of the macro, so you can use the value to compare it at later time.

Comment: I can't use those 2 Macros in the same Workbook_change Event. It wouldnt work , where do I put the first macro? Or otherwise the second one ?

Comment: You might get away with this if you used a `SelectionChange` event to store the value, but this would not work if the user changed the same cell twice without moving to another cell in between.

Comment: It doesnt seems I can get on with that. It just doesnt save the value after it gets out the macro . Check my edit to see the code im using

Comment: I didn't get... you want to save the value of the cell, or the object cell itself? Your title and text are misleading in that case!

Comment: I want to save the VALUE of the cell since I need to compare it with the new value that the user has insert.

Comment: Ok, then... in your edits, you're defining `Dim oldval As Range`, which means the variable is a range object, not simply its value. As well, you're just after setting it as a range (`Set oldval = ActiveCell`). That's why you lose the value, because you're storing the all object (and when you call its value, you will call the value after you have changed it). Replace with `Dim oldValue As String` (or Integer, or whatever else, you know your data), then `oldValue = ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: You won't be able to store the value of the cell in a local variable before it's changed using the `Worksheet_Change` method. The `Worksheet_Change` event is fired after the cell value has already been changed...  so you will end up saving the new value rather than the old value.

Comment: Having the same problem, actually, reading around the web, the Worksheet_Change event gives that issue . Seems is not a correct way to solve that problem